# Spring intercept the setting of a field in generated classes, locale issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb

We have a spring form where you can enter a amount of money, this is mapped to an 'amount' field in a class generated from xsd files by JAXB. The type is double. We need to be able to have different locales of currency entered.

Snipped from the jsp:

```
<input type="text" value="${charge.amount}" name="charges[${loop.index}].amount">
```

When entering '12.8' it is fine when I hit submit.

But entering '12,8', spring silently errors, i am assuming that 12,8 can't be set to a double.

What i think i need to do is somehow get in-between spring getting the input and then before it tries to set the value in the model object change it back to an acceptable double.